# Type "Props" is not valid in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js

When i tried to build my next project with `yarn build` it show me an error build

```
  Type error: Layout "app/dashboard/tpp/components/layout.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
  Type "Props" is not valid.
```

anyone has idea whats wrong with my code? [image: layout.tsx]

the build process not produce error

Comment: is this next13 app directory?

Comment: yes it is. im using app dir

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation. Layout in next js accept only special props.

```
TypeScript

export default function ShopLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  params: {
    tag: string
    item: string
  }
}) {
  // URL -> /shop/shoes/nike-air-max-97
  // `params` -> { tag: 'shoes', item: 'nike-air-max-97' }
  return <section>{children}</section>
}
```